# How to share comment of Python function by multiple related shotcut functions

Tags: python

I have a Python class which has a complicated method, called `send`. It has a long comment because it has many parameters.

And it has many related shotcut methods, like the following

```py
class HttpClient:

    send(self,
        method:str,
        url:str,
        params:Union[None,Dict[str,str]]=None,
        headers:Union[None,Dict[str,str]]=None, 
        data:Union[None,Dict[str,str],str,bytes]=None, 
        json:Union[None,Dict[str,str]]=None,
        request_body_encoding:Union[None,str]=None,
        debug:bool=False,
        debug_print_request_body_encoding:Union[None,str]=None,
        debug_print_response_body_encoding:Union[None,str]=None,    
        debug_print_body_max_len:int=4096,   
    ):
    """ a long comment here"""

    def  get(self, *args,**kargs):
        return send('GET',*args,**kargs)
        
    def  post(self, *args,**kargs):
        return send('POST',*args,**kargs)
        
    def  put(self, *args,**kargs):
        return send('PUT',*args,**kargs)
        
    def  delete(self, *args,**kargs):
        return send('DELETE',*args,**kargs)
```

I want all these shotcut methods have similar comments, so developers could check how to use those parameters in IDEs, like VS Code/Pycharm.

I don't want to leave duplicated copy for each method.

I know `__doc__` attribute of function could be set to reuse docstring, but how to access the `__doc__` attribute of an instance method?

And even I could do that, IDE, like VS Code seems could only display those comments in hint, the parameters in function prototype still in compact form, like args, **kargs,

[image]

it could not be unpacked like those in send method.

[image]

Comment: Function docstrings are stored in the `__doc__` attribute of the function.  So, maybe it would work to assign `get.__doc__ = send.__doc__` ?  Worth a try.